# Android: Adding more than 1 item to an arrayList and displaying it as one entry

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm trying to add 2 items to an arrayList for display.
For example:

```
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from "+ TABLE_STUDENTS, null );
    res.moveToFirst();
    while(res.isAfterLast() == false)
    {
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(ST_SURNAME)));
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(ST_FIRST_NAME)));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
```

I want the information set to view as:
Surname, first_name
e.g. Doe, Jane 
When displayed is the list view. However it currently displays as follows: 
(item 1) Doe 
(item 2) Jane

This is what I have in my List class:

```
    ArrayList array_list = mydb.getAllStudents();
    //Creating an Array Adapter to manipulate the contacts data into a ListView
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_layout, array_list);
    //Adding the contacts to the list view.
    student = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    student.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

How can I get them to be displayed as just one entry?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming your fields are named `Name` and `SurName`: `Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("SELECT Name + ' ' + SurName FROM "+ TABLE_STUDENTS, null);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines:

```
array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(ST_SURNAME)));
array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(ST_FIRST_NAME)));
```

bind surname and first name as separate entities in your ListView.

If you want to associate your data to one String like "surname, firstName" then do a simple String concatenation like this:

```
array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(ST_SURNAME)) + "," + 
               res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(ST_FIRST_NAME)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add one entry per name in the ArrayList, and format each entry the way you want it.

```
while(res.isAfterLast() == false)
{
    String name = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(ST_SURNAME)) + ", " + res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(ST_FIRST_NAME));
    array_list.add(name);
    res.moveToNext();
}
```